# HTML Encode very strange characters after decoded by ipBoard

Tags: c#, html-encode

I have never seen these characters before. I read out information from a IPBoard database and displayed them on my page. What I saw was this:

```
ï¼ˆã€€ï¾Ÿ Ð”ï¾Ÿï¼‰
```

instead of this （　ﾟ Дﾟ）
*Be careful now, that's NOT a space you are looking at in this Japanese smiley*

I used:

```
Server.HTMLDecode (and) HTMLEncode
```

but they won't work in this case.

Have you had any experience on this before and want to elaborate?

Comment: It looks like a binary data.
I've removed `cryptography` tag, because text encoding has nothing to do with it. I suppose you should remove it from the title also, or explain more

Comment: @Darine: I wish I had more details to add... I wish I had more code to add to this particular problem...

Comment: @Darine: :( I know.. I know.. It's not an easy question since not many of us have had deal with Japanese encoded characters in our career.. it's ok Darine. no worries.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the bin-hex representation of the UTF-8 encoding of 　`ﾟ Дﾟ` then it looks like:

```
ef bc 88 e3 80 80 ef be 9f 20 d0 94 ef be 9f ef bc 89
```

I you interpret this data as an Windows-1252 encoded string, then you get:

```
ï¼ˆã€€ï¾Ÿ Ð”ï¾Ÿï¼‰
```

So it looks like the IPBoard database returns an UTF-8 encoded string that the server or the browser is interpreting as a Windows-1252 string.

If it is the browser, then make sure that the http response headers indicate that the response is UTF-8 `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` or add the following meta tag in the html header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an encoding problem. The sequence needs to be read as UTF-8:

```
        byte[] bytes = {
                           0xEF, 0xBC, 0x88, 0xE3,
                           0x80, 0x80, 0xEF, 0xBE,
                           0x9F, 0x20, 0xD0, 0x94,
                           0xEF, 0xBE, 0x9F, 0xEF,
                           0xBC, 0x89, 0x0D, 0x0A,
                           0xEF, 0xBE, 0x9F
                       };
        string t = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(t);
```